Is Paramagnetic Current Density Operator Hermite?
When free electrons are exposed to the electromagnetic field, the current density operator has a modification, which can be divided into so-called paramagnetic and diamagnetic parts:
\begin{align}
j_p&=-\frac{ie}{2m}[\psi^\dagger(\nabla\psi)-(\nabla\psi^\dagger)\psi]\\
j_d&=-\frac{e^2}{m}A\psi^\dagger\psi
\end{align}
I know both of them are not gauge independent but their sum is. So both of them alone is not measurable but their sum is. As a consequence, the sum of them should be Hermite. Since $j_d$ is obviously Hermite, so$j_p$ must also be Hermite. But I found $j_p$ seems to be totally anti-Hermite where I recognize:
\begin{equation}
\nabla^\dagger=-\nabla
\end{equation}
Thus $[\psi^\dagger(\nabla\psi)]^\dagger=-(\nabla\psi^\dagger)\psi$, but an extra $i$ makes things confusing.
